# Windows batch variable expansion not working properly

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm facing some unexpected output when I store the driveletter from `%0` into a variable.

The following snippet is run from **C:\Temp\Test**:

```
@echo off
for %%I in ("%~0") do set "Target=%%~dI"
echo Target:  %Target%
pushd %Target% && echo Current: %CD% || echo Failed to change dir!
```

This prints the correct value for `Target` but not for the current directory:

```
Target:  C:
Current: C:\Temp\Test
```

Expected output:

```
Target:  C:
Current: C:\
```

I also tried the same code with delayed expansion but this didn't work either. Can anybody explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not with variable expansion, but with `pushd` behavior.

this scenario may explain how `pushd` (or `cd` btw) works

```
C:\>cd temp
C:\temp>_
```

now `%cd%` is `c:\temp`. If you "move" to another drive

```
C:\temp>e:
```

and try

```
E:\>pushd c:
C:\temp>_
```

see that now `%cd%` is back `C:\temp`, and not to `C:\` as you were expecting.

but

```
C:\temp>e:
E:\>pushd c:\
C:\>_
```

brings `%cd%` to `C:\` as you were expecting.

so, your .BAT file may be simply written as

```
pushd %~d0\
```

Comment: +1, Just recognized myself the same :-), but the output was still buggy

Comment: The trailing backslash in `pushd %dp0` was the key, thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, I meant "the _missing_ trailing backslash".

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect `Current: C:\`?
You runs the script from `C:\Temp\Test`.
So it's correct that `%CD%` expands to `C:\Temp\Test`.

If you expecte that `%CD%` should change as you use `PUSHD %target%` you need to split the line, or use delayed expansion for `!CD!`, as at first the complete line is parsed and the percent expansion is done, before your `PUSHD` is executed.

The other problem is that `pushd C:` doesn't change the path, as `C:` is a relative path, you need to to use `C:\`

```
@echo off
set "Target=%~d0\"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Target:  %Target%
pushd %Target% && echo Current: !CD! || echo Failed to change dir^^!
```

Comment: `set /?` says that `%CD%` expands to the current directory name. `pushd /?` says that it switches to the given directory. So I think my expectation is reasonable. The code you suggested gives me the exact same output as mine (on Win XP).

Answer (score 0):

I cant explain you this behaviour but you can mimic it using :

```
pushd %Target%
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (echo Current: %CD%) else (echo Failed to change dir!)
```